# What is the difference between rounding Decimals with quantize vs the built in round function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, decimal, rounding

When working with the built in decimal module in python I can round decimals as follows.

```py
Decimal(50.212345).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
> Decimal('50.21')
```

But I can also round the same number with the built in round function

```py
round(Decimal(50.212345), 2)
> Decimal('50.21')
```

Why would I use one instead of the other when rounding Decimals? In previous answers about rounding decimals, users suggested to use quantize because the built in round function would return a value of type float. Based on my testing, these both return a Decimal. Other than syntax, is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) for `round()` says: "for a general Python object `number`, `round` delegates to `number.__round__`", so it doesn't sound like there would be any difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The return types aren't *always* the same. `round()` used with a single argument actually returns an `int`:

```
>>> round(5.3)
5
>>> round(decimal.Decimal("5.3"))
5
```

Other than that, suit yourself. `quantize()` is especially handy if you want a deoimal rounded to "the same" precision as another decimal you already have.

```
>>> x = decimal.Decimal("123.456")
>>> x*x
Decimal('15241.383936')
>>> (x*x).quantize(x)
Decimal('15241.384')
```

See? The code doing this doesn't have to know that `x` originally had 3 digits after the decimal point. Just passing `x` to `quantize()` forces the function to round back to the same precision as the original `x`, regardless of what that may be.

`quantize()` is also necessary if you want to use a rounding mode other than the default nearest/even.

```
>>> (x*x).quantize(x, decimal.ROUND_FLOOR)
Decimal('15241.383')
```